# How to use a fork of a repository in my workflows?

Tags: github, github-actions

My current workflow is as such:

```yaml
steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
    - uses: nikeee/setup-pandoc@v1
    # do stuff
```

My problem is the current implementation of the `setup-pandoc` action is not compatible with macOS build. I already created a PR which is waiting for aproval and release. In the meantime I would like my CI to stop complaining. Is it possible to rely on my fork of the repository (`12rambau/setup-pandoc`) instead, even though it's not published in the marketplace?

Comment: Did you try it? The marketplace is just for discovery.

Comment: Yes, see [`jobs.<job_id>.steps[*].uses`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsuses).

Comment: I didn't realize action version were just regular tags, I used @Gereon's solution and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use your fork. Change your workflow file like so:

```
steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
    - uses: 12rambau/setup-pandoc@BRANCH
```

where `BRANCH` should be replaced with the branch in your repo.